# When did India-Pakistan border fencing start?

Tags: india, pakistan, borders

- [1500 KM. FENCING COMPLETED IN PUNJAB AND RAJASTHAN SECTOR](https://archive.pib.gov.in/archive/releases98/lyr2003/rjun2003/04062003/r040620034.html)

This link says that India was building a fence along the Pakistan border. The news is dated June 2003.

When did they start fencing the Indo-Pak border exactly?

Also, here they are talking about Rajasthan and Punjab. What about Kashmir? When did they fence Kashmir?

Comment: A lot of the [border](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India%E2%80%93Pakistan_border) is very mountainous so I don't see how they'd build a fence, or maintain and guard it. It also doesn't make much sense to build a border fence when you're disputing where the border is.

Comment: @StuartF When there is a disputed border, then building a border fence is a good way to establish your idea of the border as a fact. Individual violations of "your" border can no longer claim to be accidental, which prevents mass violations from establishing a customary right. But it does of course risk an escalation of the conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It started in Punjab in the late 1980s and in Jammu-Kashmir in 1994:

> Construction of the fences began in the late 1980s in the state of Punjab when India faced an armed Sikh separatist uprising, and weapons were being smuggled from Pakistan. In 1994, India pushed ahead with the construction of fences along the border of Jammu and Kashmir. The building process was stopped because of relentless Pakistani fire but resumed again along the international border in Jammu in early 2001. As of November 2009, of the 2,044 kilometers identified for fencing along the India-Pakistan border, 1,916 kilometers had been completed, 1,862 kilometers had been floodlit and 148 kilometers of planned floodlighting remains to be completed.

[The source of this quote](https://books.openedition.org/obp/4561?lang=en) has footnotes but some of the links are dead.